# In javascript, is there an efficient way to write this function that converts a timestamp to local time?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, time

I've written a function that will get the first line of an "Activity Array" because it holds the timestamp within the response.

That timestamp looks like this: `20220714.1757`

The function below will output: `7/14/2022 12:57:00 PM`

This is great and exactly what I wanted; however, I feel like my code is bloated, dirty, and inefficient. Is there an efficient way to write this function? I'm self-taught so I welcome any materials or references to learn more.

```js
function get_timestamp(activityArray) {
    let timestampBlock = activityArray[0];
    let timestamp_array = timestampBlock.split(".");
    let dateBlock = timestamp_array[0];
    let timeBlock = timestamp_array[1];
    let date_array = dateBlock.split("");
    let year = date_array[0] + date_array[1] + date_array[2] + date_array[3];
    let month = date_array[4] + date_array[5];
    let day = date_array[6] + date_array[7];
    let date = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
    let time_array = timeBlock.split("");
    let hour = time_array[0] + time_array[1];
    let minute = time_array[2] + time_array[3];
    let time = new Date(date + "T" + hour + ":" + minute + "Z");
    console.log(date + "T" + hour + ":" + minute + "Z")
    let formatted_time = time.toLocaleString();
    let formatted_time_array = formatted_time.split(",");
    let timestamp = formatted_time_array[0] + " " + formatted_time_array[1];
    return timestamp;
}

console.log(get_timestamp(["20220714.1757"]));
```

Comment: This question may be better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) since you're asking for help improving your working code (which can be subjective and does not have a specific right or wrong answer).  Stack Overflow is meant to resolve errors in non-working code.

Comment: You're right. I'm just getting back to coding and Stack Overflow was my first option I thought of. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the date parts nicely with a regular expression. Then you can feed those as separate arguments to `Date.UTC`, so you avoid string parsing. Only have to take care to make the month number zero-based:

```js
function get_timestamp(str) {
    return new Date(Date.UTC(
        ...str.match(/^....|\d\d/g).map((p, i) => p - !--i)
    )).toLocaleString('en-US').replace(",", "");
}

console.log(get_timestamp('20220714.1757'));
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing that cleans up code is to put the params of recurring operations into data. Here, `fields` describes where to expect elements of the date in the input string.

You may have some other reason to convert to a JS date and then format as an ISO string, then manipulate that string, but the trip seems circuitous. Here, we just interpolate the captured date elements into a new string.

(side note: your example input of 17:57 probably means 5:57 PM using a 12 hour clock -- not 12:57 as the OP suggests)

```js
function get_timestamp(str) {
  const fields = [
    { key: 'year', start: 0, end: 4 },
    { key: 'month', start: 4, end: 6 },
    { key: 'day', start: 6, end: 8 },
    { key: 'hour', start: 9, end: 11 },
    { key: 'minute', start: 11, end: 13 }
  ];

  // produces { year: '2022', month: '07', ...
  const d = fields.reduce((acc, el) => {
    acc[el.key] = str.slice(el.start, el.end);
    return acc;
  }, {})
  // convert to 12-hour clock
  d.ampm = d.hour > 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
  if (d.ampm === 'PM') d.hour -= 12;
  // format using string interpolation
  return `${d.month}/${d.day}/${d.year} ${d.hour}:${d.minute}:00 ${d.ampm}`
}

const activityArray = ['20220714.1757']
console.log(get_timestamp(activityArray[0]))
```

Comment: The difference in hour (17:57 versus 12:57) is consequence of timezone. The date is input as an ISO date, but output in locale's timezone. Your function is not outputting the date in local time, as the asker had. But as they accepted this answer, I suppose they like it better this way.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function convert_timestamp(timestamp) {
  function convert_timestamp(timestamp) {
  const hour = parseInt(timestamp.slice(9, 11)) + 2;
  return `${timestamp.slice(6, 8)}/${timestamp.slice(4, 6)}/${timestamp.slice(0, 4)} ${hour > 24 ? (hour - 24).toString().padStart(2, "0") : hour.toString().padStart(2, "0")}:${timestamp.slice(11, 13)}:00`
}

console.log(convert_timestamp("20220714.2357")) // 14/07/2022 01:57:00
}
```

Simple one liner.